# Jquery Search box to search link from Side Verticle Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a search box for my horizontal menu.

```
<div class="nav">
    Search Menu : <input type="text" name="search"/>
    <br/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Link1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link3 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link4 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link5 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link6 </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to search `link1` and it sort and show `link1` and when I clear search I want my original menu. Is it possible to achieve ?

Comment: Specify what you've tried, a non-working/half-working fiddle. No one will code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <script> 


$(document).ready(function () {


$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
if (this.value.length > 0) {   
  $("li").hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#search").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
  }).show(); 
}  
else { 
  $("li").show();
}
}); 

});

    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KG637/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
Search Menu : <input type="text" name="search" id='txtSearch'/>
<br/>
<ul>
<li><a class='list' id='link1' href="#"> Link1 </a></li>
<li><a class='list' id='link2' href="#"> Link2 </a></li>
<li><a class='list' id='link3' href="#"> Link3 </a></li>
<li><a class='list' id='link4' href="#"> Link4 </a></li>
<li><a class='list' id='link5' href="#"> Link5 </a></li>
<li><a class='list' id='link6' href="#"> Link6 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var linklist = $('.list');
var myarr = [];
for (i = 0; i < linklist.length ; i++) {
    myarr.push(linklist[i].text.trim().toLowerCase())
}
$('#txtSearch').keyup(function(){
   var text = $('#txtSearch').val().toLowerCase();
   var found = myarr.indexOf(text);
    if(found >-1)
    {        
        $('#' + text).css('background-color','Yellow');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.list').css('background-color','White');
    }
});
});
```

[See the demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qDPem/6/)

**EDIT**

Updated fiddle to ignore case sensitivity.